# Multiselect attribute created not saving in Db

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, source-model

I have created a custom Multiselect product attribute. It has been created successfully but the value are saved when assigned store view specific.

But if i select an option and save in global it is not saving.Anything else i am missing?

Step1: setup file InstallData.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,  ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

       $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
           'attr_code',
           [
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => 'Attr Label',
              'input' => 'multiselect',
              'sort_order' => 2,
              'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
              'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
              'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
              'visible' => true,
              'required' => false,
              'user_defined' => false,
              'filterable' => true,
              'used_in_product_listing' => true,
          ]
      );
   }
}
```

Step2: Source Model

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

   public function getAllOptions()
   {
       $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __('Label1'), 'value'=>'0'],
            ['label' => __('Label2'), 'value'=>'1'],
        ];
        return $this->_options;
   }

   public function toOptionArray()
   {
       $arr = $this->getAllOptions();
       $_options = [];
       foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
          $_options[] = [
              'value' => $key,
              'label' => $value
          ];
       }

      return $_options;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not set when creating attribute

**like below:**

```
'option' => ['values' => [
            'Option 1',
            'Option 2',
            'Option 3',
            ],
        ],
```

[for more please check below blog](https://www.catgento.com/2017/04/20/magento-2-create-multiselect-product-attribute-programmatically/)

Comment: It is for adding option statically in setup file..But i have source model for this attribute..

Answer (score 0):

Add your attribute to the attribute group

> ```
> $setId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityType); 
> $groupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityType, $setId); 
> $groupName = $eavSetup->getGroupName($entityType, $setId, $groupId, 'attribute_group_name');
> ```

And also change the `user_defined` to `true` and add `'group' => $groupName`

Comment: This needs to be add in setup file ?

Comment: @aravind yes, those changes needs to be done in setup file.

Comment: ok will check and update you @Anshu Mishra